# How to use retrieved String from SharedPreferences

Tags: android, string, compare, sharedpreferences

I have a couple of ListPreferences that my PreferenceActivity displays. From the class that launches this activity, I listen to any changes on the SharedPreferences and use getString(String key, String default) to obtain the selected option.

When I retrieve this String, I need to perform certain operations depending on what String it is. But, how would I use the String. If it was an int, I could have used switch case but what do I do with Strings?

Is there any other way apart from using if-else and using String.equals to compare the 2 strings? 
Or is there a way to retrieve the selected position instead of the selected String?

Comment: Have you tried with try catch block? Convert the value to int using Integer.parseInt(value) , if value is int then no pblm , if it is String you will get Exception handle it accordingly.. I think you should use NumberFormatException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store all your `String`s into a `HashMap`, along with corresponding `int` values and then have a `switch` case on the `int`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int k = 0;
    String i = "Namratha"; // replace the value from Shared Preference
    try {
        k = Integer.parseInt(i);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v("Exception**********", e.getMessage());
    }
```

See if value is **String** it will **throws Exception** and go to **catch block** so that you can 
understand calue from preference is String.. Do you stuffs inside catch block accordingly..

Else if the value is **int** then do your stuffs inside **try block**.

Answer (score 0):

If you must have an int signifying the position, you could use a String array and the Arrays.binarySearch method

```
private static final String[] VALUES = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };

public void processSelection( String selectedValue ) {  
    int pos = Arrays.binarySearch( VALUES, selectedValue );

    switch (pos) {
    case 0:
        ... 
    break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```